# Creating a number pyramid with tabularx

Tags: tables, tabularx

I am trying to create a simple number pyramid like [this one](https://www.gut-erklaert.de/images/mathematik/zahlenpyramide-zahlenturm-zahlenmauer-1.jpg) using a tabularx table with six columns and `\multicolumn' commands.

I tried

```
\begin{tabularx}{0.5\linewidth}{XXXXXX}
        \cline{3-4}
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{}&\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{}\\
        \cline{2-5}
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{}&\multicolumn{2}{|c}{}&\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{}\\
        \hline
        \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{$\frac{3}{2}$}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{$\frac{1}{3}$}&\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{$\frac{1}{2}$}\\
        \hline
 \end{tabularx}
```

.. which gives  me a very distorted table.

However if I add a simple empty line to the table with

```
&&&&&&
```

everything looks perfect. My only issue now is that the table is too long, because of that extra empty line.

Is there a way to get a pretty pyramid without adding that extra line?

Answer (score 6):

With some low level programming:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\newcommand{\block}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}%
  \vrule width0pt height \blockdim
  \ooalign{%
    \framebox[\blockdim]{\rule{0pt}{\blockdim}}\cr
    \hidewidth\raisebox{0.5\dimexpr\blockdim-\height}{\raisebox{\depth}{#1}}\hidewidth\cr
  }%
  \endgroup
}
\newcommand{\joinblocks}{\unskip\kern-\fboxrule\ignorespaces}
\newenvironment{blocks}[1][1cm]
 {\begin{varwidth}{\textwidth}\setlength{\blockdim}{#1}\makeblocks}
 {\end{varwidth}}
\newcommand{\makeblocks}{%
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`&\lowercase{\endgroup\let~}\joinblocks
  \catcode`\&=\active
  \baselineskip=0pt
  \lineskiplimit=\maxdimen
  \lineskip=0pt
  \centering
}
\newlength{\blockdim}

\begin{document}

A pyramid
\begin{blocks}
  \block{1}\\
  \block{2} & \block{3} \\
  \block{4} & \block{5} & \block{$\dfrac{36}{6}$}
\end{blocks}
in context

\bigskip

A pyramid
\begin{blocks}[1.5cm]
  \block{1}\\
  \block{2} & \block{3} \\
  \block{4} & \block{5} & \block{$\dfrac{36}{6}$}
\end{blocks}
in context

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

drawing this number pyramid is much simpler than write it as table. especially if you like to use `tabularx` table environment. by use of the `tikz` package you can obtain:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 0pt,
every node/.style = {draw, minimum size=7mm, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt}
                        ]
\node (n1)  {};
%
\node (n11) [below left=of n1.south]    {};
\node (n12) [right=of n11]              {};
%
\node (n21) [below left=of n11.south]   {$\frac{1}{3}$};
\node (n22) [right=of n21]              {$\frac{1}{3}$};
\node (n23) [right=of n22]              {$\frac{1}{2}$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**addendum:** 
with use of the `chains` library it is possible to achieve a little bit shorter code:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains, positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 0pt,
      start chain = going right,
every node/.style = {draw, minimum size=7mm, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt,
                     on chain}
                        ]
\node (n1)  {};
%
\node (n11) [below left=of n1.south]    {};
\node       {};
%
\node (n21) [below left=of n11.south]   {$\frac{1}{3}$};
\node       {$\frac{1}{3}$};
\node       {$\frac{1}{2}$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

result is the same as before.

Answer (score 2):

This is really just for fun. Draw the pyramid via a recursion defined using `tikzmath`. If you want to increase `\nmax` even further, you need to make the list `\LstNum` longer. Of course, you can put in this list whatever numbers you like.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\begin{document}
\def\LstNum{{1,2,4,8,16}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6,evaluate={
        function pyramid(\n, \q) {
    if \n == 1 then {
      return chi(\q);
    } else {
      return int(pyramid(\n-1, \q) + pyramid(\n-1, \q+1));
    };
  };},
declare function={chi(\i)=\LstNum[int(\i-1)];}]
\begin{scope}
\def\nmax{3}
\foreach \Z [evaluate=\Z as \Xmax using {int(1+\nmax-\Z)}]in {1,...,\nmax}
{\foreach \X in {1,...,\Xmax}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myp}{pyramid(\Z,\X)}
\node[draw,minimum size=0.6cm] at (\X+\Z/2,\Z) {\myp};}
\node at (2.5,-0.6) {$n_\mathrm{max}=3$};
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[xshift=4cm]
\def\nmax{4}
\foreach \Z [evaluate=\Z as \Xmax using {int(1+\nmax-\Z)}]in {1,...,\nmax}
{\foreach \X in {1,...,\Xmax}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myp}{pyramid(\Z,\X)}
\node[draw,minimum size=0.6cm] at (\X+\Z/2,\Z) {\myp};}
\node at (3,-0.6) {$n_\mathrm{max}=4$};
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[xshift=9cm]
\def\nmax{5}
\foreach \Z [evaluate=\Z as \Xmax using {int(1+\nmax-\Z)}]in {1,...,\nmax}
{\foreach \X in {1,...,\Xmax}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myp}{pyramid(\Z,\X)}
\node[draw,minimum size=0.6cm] at (\X+\Z/2,\Z) {\myp};}
\node at (3.5,-0.6) {$n_\mathrm{max}=5$};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]